# Is the Sigma 35mm worth it for an APS-C?

Tags: digital

I am a beginning photographer and want to upgrade my gear. I have a crop sensor Canon camera and usually use a 50mm 1.8 lens for my portraits. Recently I have been looking at the Sigma 35mm 1.4 lens but not sure if buying it would be worth it.

Comment: We can't decide if it's worth it to you. Obviously it's worth it to *someone* or it wouldn't be on the market.

Comment: What are you worried about? If you focus more on what you need to make your own decision, we can be more helpful.

Comment: "I am a beginning photographer and want to upgrade my gear." - Early onset [GAS](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98948/75526) is particularly insidious with poor prognosis.

Comment: Anyone offering you advice without getting to the heart of what you really need isn't a friend, they're a salesman. The better question is *can x lens help me do y photography?* **That** question can be answered objectively. At that point, whether or not the particular lens is *worth it* is completely up to you - but at least then, you'll have some facts.

Comment: What would you be able to do with the 35mm 1.4 that you can't with the 50mm 1.8? (and some sneaker zoom)

Comment: @FábioDias Sneaker zoom ?  Who makes that, Nike or Adidas ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan New Balance. Best IS/VR in the game.

Comment: [Considerations when purchasing a prime lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/137/75526)

Comment: @Hueco I'm an ASICS man. NB toe boxes are too small for my duck feet.

Comment: Until the OP tells us what they wish to gain by using the 35mm Sigma lens instead of the 50mm Canon lens, this question is impossible to answer. Voting to close as "Unclear what you are asking."

Comment: @MichaelC I spent just shy of 20 years rock climbing, 10 of which at a competitive level wearing size 8 downturns like these https://evolvsports.com/shaman/ (I wear a size 10 street shoe). Yes, I'm fairly certain my toe box is permanently bent in...but every street shoe toe box now feels positively spacious.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't upgrade your gear unless you *know why you are doing it*.  'Because I like playing with new gadgets' is a perfectly good (well, maybe not so good), and very common reason, but instead I'll concentrate on possible reasons which have some photographic aspect.

There are, really two of these:

1. because the lens you have is not good enough quality;
2. because the lens you have won't do something you need it to do apart from in the limited sense of raw quality.

I will disregard (1) because I am quite sure that the 50/1.8 Canon lens is perfectly fine.  People obsess both about absolute lens quality and about the magic qualities of certain lenses and like to think that these qualities will somehow make a huge difference to their photographs.  Almost always they won't. And before you dismiss me as not understanding lenses: I have a rather substantial collection of lenses some of which are claimed to have near-mystical qualities (and in some cases actually mystical qualities), and at least one of which I had specially fabricated by gnomes from sand imported from the Moon.  I love them, especially the lunar ones, but they just don't make me a great photographer.

So that leaves (2): will the new lens do something photographically interesting the old one won't?  Well, yes, it will:

1. it is about half a stop faster;
2. it is wider – its field of view is different;
3. ... and there may be some other features associated with this specific lens which I don't know about.

For (1): half a stop isn't much: you won't get shallower DoF really as the lens is also wider, and it's just not that much of a gain.  Don't buy it for this.

For (3) I don't know.  Perhaps there are some considerations specific to this particular lens and/or camera combination.

But (2) is the big question, and where it comes to *knowing why you want it*.

The 50mm lens you have is a mildly long lens on a crop-sensor camera.  It is probably a lovely lens for portraits, but it's rather long for the way people tend to use lenses for, say, street or environmental photography.

The 35mm lens is going to be much closer to the traditional 'standard' field of view.  It is still quite a lot longer than a lot of people use (Canon's APS-C crop factor is 1.6X, not 1.5X like most everyone else), but a lot of cameras used to come with lenses of 55mm which (remember this was for 35mm film) has about the same field of view as this lens when used on a crop body.

So, well, what do *you* want to be able to do?  If what you want to do is make portraits of people then the 50mm you have is probably close to ideal.  If what you want to be able to do is more like street photography, then the 35mm may be better, but you might also consider something wider: With Canon's 1.6X crop factor a *24mm* lens would be about equivalent to 35-40mm on full frame in terms of field of view, and this is a lovely length.

So, as I said, it depends on what *you* want to do, and *only you can answer that question*.  In particular the 35mm lens is *not* just a better version of the lens you have: even if it is better, it's not the same field of view, and would want to be used in a different way.

Comment: Seems important to reinforce the "What _you_ as a _photographer_ want out of a lens" point, not just "Other photographers say its better..." - The rare time I do 'street photography' I'm typically using 85mm+ on my canon crop sensor to 'drill into details of a scene'. A friend, with the same camera, uses nothing but a 4.5mm fisheye to 'capture everything of a scene'...

Comment: @TheLuckless: I've changed it to emphasize 'what *you* want to do'.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know in your special case, but generally speaking it is definitely worth it. On APS-C it works as a normal lens (that is ~50 mm) of a tremendous quality.

On full frame is a little wide but the quality is outstanding from edge to edge starting from F/1.8. [Here is an example](https://asceticexperience.com/portfolio/how-to-see-the-others-defects-through-spiritual-understanding/). I use it extensively on my Full Frame Canon. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: "On full frame is a little wide" - if there was a line in the sand separating wide lenses from normal, the 35mm would be standing on it. It's a wide angle lens, no doubt, but it only gets *more* wide from there. Your sentence gives the impression that 35mm is a tad too wide, when in fact, it's not.

Comment: "I don't know in your special case" - How can it be "definitely worth it" if it might not be suitable for OP's photographic objectives?

Comment: *generally speaking* is worth it.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have the 35 mm. But I have the 50 and the 20 mm.

I bought the Canon 50 mm 1.8 just as you then wanted something better.
Bought the Sigma 50 mm 1.4 Art and almost got religious.

I recently bought the 20 mm after a long search after which was the best.
Here is a good review of the 35 mm Christopher has in my opinion very good reviews https://youtu.be/qzxiAZ90S5o .
And since you are on APS-C then 35 mm is not very wide.
I believe you should go wider.

The 20 mm I have has its drawbacks too, I can't use filters* and it's really really heavy.
The 24 mm does not have the bulging front lens so that could means filters are possible.

Then there is the 18-35 mm 1.8 for APS-C.
It's the same aperture as you have but a zoom that will get you covered for the most part.
Me personally are not interested in zooms and I feel the 1.8 is too high. But it's all personal preference.

I can also completely dismiss the "Sigma lenses can't focus on Canon cameras".
That is just plain wrong. They focus fine.
With my limited experience of 10-ish lenses, they focus the fastest.

`*` I **can** use filters but that means I need to use square filters and that is not great when I mostly have the camera hanging on my shoulder.
If I was a landscape fotographer or something more stationary with a tripod then I would invest in it but as it is now. No thanks...

Comment: "I feel the 1.8 is too high" - it's 2/3 stop up from your 20mm f/1.4. Hardly a difference to write home about.

Comment: "but that means I need to use square filters and that is not great when I mostly have the camera hanging on my shoulder." - Square systems are designed for easy on/off attachment so that you can pocket the filters when on the move. That being said, I leave mine on (and the camera attached to the tripod too!) when moving and have never had the filter group fall.

Comment: @hueco it's not about the amount of extra light you get at 1.4 vs 1.8. it's about how much you need to stop it down to get good results. I generally stop my 1.4's down to about 2-2.2. doing the same on a 1.8 means (if all is equal) it would be lots harder to separate the background. What kind of filters are you talking about there? Keep in mind this lens does not have any filter threads to mount on so please show me what that "easy" on and off means.

Comment: The DoF for a 20mm lens focused 2 feet away at f/2 is 0.25ft total. At f/2.8 it is 0.35ft total - for a difference of only .1ft or ~a single inch. Complaining about a lens no longer able to throw a background while still using sub f/2.8 is disingenuous at best. Even focused at 10 feet, the DoF is 7' and 11' respectively. Past that and you're going out to infinity anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Only you can say, but I would suggest it's not worth it. For what purpose would you use it? Also, Sigma lenses on DSLR Canons can focus poorly, especially when shooting through the viewfinder (phase detect autofocus being used), because everything is reverse engineered in the lens - camera communications.

50/1.8 gets you more background blur than 35/1.4, because 50/1.8 = 27.778 whereas 35/1.4 = 25 exactly. If that's what you are after, shoot with 50/1.8.

If slightly wider field of view with nearly the same (slightly less) amount of background blur is what you're after, i.e. if you want a different shooting distance for portraits (shoot closer), then perhaps 35/1.4 would be the right lens of you. It may be a bit long as a walkaround lens, though.

For crop sensor Canon, 35mm real focal length is equivalent to 56mm (35mm equivalent). It's not a standard lens, it's a very very slight tele (although it's on the boundary between standard and slight tele). The difference between 35mm and 50mm is not THAT large. I suggest you shouldn't own both 35mm and 50mm at the same time unless you collect lenses.

Standard lens for crop Canons would be anything between 22mm - 30mm or so.

There is a 24mm f/2.8 lens, but unfortunately, for crop cameras, the f/2.8 does not allow you to get massive depth of field effects.

There is too a 28mm f/1.8 but it's significantly more expensive than 24mm f/2.8. Also, you don't get as much background blur with 28/1.8 as you would get with 50/1.8. But, as a standard lens, perhaps background blur is not what you're after?

If you're looking for a standard prime lens, consider choosing between 28mm f/1.8 and 24mm f/2.8. The 24mm f/2.8 is so cheap anyway that it is worth getting. For 24mm f/2.8, you are getting a good amount of sharpness at a very reasonable cost, although it does have vignetting when wide open.

A consideration may be if you plan to update to full frame someday. 28mm f/1.8 works on full frame, 24mm f/2.8 doesn't (but the latter is very cheap anyway, and you can sell it if you decide to do the update).

I decided to pick 24mm f/2.8 to complement my 50mm f/1.8. I was happy with the choice, but I ended up updating to full frame.

Don't forget longer focal lengths. The 85mm f/1.8 lens is very good value for money, and if you ever update to full frame, takes the place of the 50mm f/1.8. It's useful on crop too as a longer tele too, to obtain even more background blur than 50mm f/1.8.

Comment: 1. Background blur isn't everything.  2. The difference in background blur between 35/1.4 and 50/1.8 with same subject size is marginal.  (Handful of pixels when pixel peeping.)  Lens characteristics can more than make up the difference.  3. FOV at same distance can affect whether getting a shot is possible in tighter spaces with 35 vs 50.  4. The switch to "equivalent" focal lengths makes it look like you're comparing 56 vs 50.  The diff between 35 and 50 is equiv to the diff between 56 and 80.  5. 35mm ("56mm”) is still in the normal range.

Comment: *Sigma lenses on DSLR Canons can focus poorly*. Would you have a URL that support this? I have three Sigma lenses and they focus properly on my Canon cameras.

Comment: @xenoid hell, I have a Sigma from back in the film days (it is long out of production) - even it focuses just fine - tested on an EOS Rebel (film), 1V, 20D, 5Dmk2.

Comment: I have exactly one non-Canon lens. I also have exactly one lens which refuses to focus if the initial guess is too much off, even though my EOS RP has the setting for trying always focusing by scanning the entire range. You can guess whether the non-Canon lens is the same as the lens which refuses to focus.

Comment: I agree on background blur, this is why I suggested 24mm f/2.8 which is terrible in background blur but the focal length is more useful as a standard lens and clearly more distinct from 50mm than the 35mm is.

Comment: @juhist Did you ever consider that this AF problem might be specific to your copy instead of a brand-wide issue? That generalization is the main point of concern here.

Comment: @FábioDias I currently assume it's firmware-related (incompatibility of lens firmware with new EOS RP). Meaning, the 3rd party manufacturer could fix it if they had enough resources and enough information for that. My lens is serial no 1468, so apparently the 3rd party manufacturer makes very little of these lenses. I'll update the firmware of the lens (and hope it behaves better after that), but the point still stands. I have never had to update the firmware on any Canon lens.

Comment: @juhist Sorry, but that's still one data point. You can't reasonably say that all "sigma lenses on DSLR Canons can focus poorly" based on a _single_ example. That's not statistically relevant based on the content of just the comments here, let alone the whole universe of sigma lens in the market.

Comment: @FábioDias I presume you didn't see the word "can". Not only that, but I'm pretty sure the manufacturers use the same firmware for multiple lenses. If one lens has firmware issues, it's likely many other lenses from the manufacturer have the same firmware issues.

Comment: https://www.the-digital-picture.com/News/News-Post.aspx?News=24518

Comment: Many old Tamrons required firmware update to work with EOS R / Nikon Z: https://www.tamron.eu/service/compatibility-nikon-z-and-canon-eos-r/

Comment: Even here on Photo SE, people acknowledge 3rd party lenses have firmware bugs: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/92456/glitching-autofocus-on-sigma-lens

Comment: Autofocus with Sigma and EOS RP crashes all the time: https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/EOS/Autofocus-crashing-with-sigma-lenses-on-Canon-EOS-RP/td-p/276748

Comment: Sigma lenses need firmware V2 to work with Canon's RF mount: http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/sigma-compatibility-notes-for-canon-rf/

Comment: Compatibility issues with 3rd party lenses: https://www.flickr.com/groups/2026654@N25/discuss/72157636379017463/

Comment: Anyone who hasn't been living under rock since Sigma ART primes began appearing on the scene should know of widespread reports about AF inconsistencies when using ART primes with Canon EOS cameras.